# Get sum of two columns and save it to variable

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL, I have field ID, price, and date field (timestamp).

I want to, at end of the month, calculate total cost for that month and save it to variable $monthjuly.

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM app WHERE YEAR(datum) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(datum) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)"
```

I tried via this command to output results, but I am not getting any result with this metod.
Where is my mistake here?

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. 
When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. 
You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help :-)

Comment: Yes Fred, I didn't write that I tried but I can't move forward untill I solve this issue, sorry for not letting folks know that in my first message in this question.

SELECT SUM(price) FROM app 
WHERE YEAR(datum) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(datum) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)"

Comment: @FabianCannes, didn't see that your edited your post.  I've updated my answer with a working SQL statement.  Basically you are using an aggregation, SUM, which requires you to also have a GROUP BY.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
You are doing a SUM with no grouping of data.  Whenever you aggregate data you need to have a grouping.  In this case we group by year and month.

Demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d952a3/1

```
SELECT SUM(price), year(datum), month(datum)
FROM app
WHERE
    YEAR(datum) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND MONTH(datum) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY YEAR(datum), MONTH(datum)
```

Comment: Not sure how mail applies here.

Comment: OP originally said he/she wanted to get the results and email them with the timing controlled by a cron job.

Comment: If that was in a comment it's been retracted, so I think you're off in the weeds here.

Comment: I responded before the text was edited.  Anyways, I've posted an updated answer for the SQL.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.

Comment: What can I say except that I did not know OP had edited the answer until I saw your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mention server, application and DB details so I am sharing you overview of functionality to achieve your requirement.

step 1 : You need to add function in your application which will call using URL. and that function should should have following code,

```
function foo() {
    // compare today date and check is it last day of month or not
    if($islastday) {
        // fetch data from sql current month
        //SELECT sum(cost)
        //FROM table
        //WHERE MONTH(date field) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
        //AND YEAR(date field) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())

        //write mail function and send mail with email template providing it 
        sql data
    }
}
```

step 2 : set cron job for daily basis to call above function.

Thanks.